# Guava retryer that calls a function until an exception occurs

Tags: java, guava

Say I have some code like this:

```java
public void deleteResource(UUID resourceId) {
    deleteFromDb();
    deleteFromALotOfOtherPlaces();    // Takes a long time!
}

public DescribeResourceResult describeResource(UUID resourceId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    return getResourceDescription(resourceId);
}
```

Unfortunately, the delete doesn't signal that it's completed. The only way to verify that the deletion has completed is to call `describeResource` which will throw an exception if the resource has been deleted.

I want to write a retryer that will repeatedly call `describeResrouce` until a `ResourceNotFoundException` occurs. How can I do that?

Here's what I have so far:

```java
final Retryer<ResourceNotFoundException> deleteResourceRetryer = RetryerBuilder.<ResourceNotFoundException>newBuilder()
                .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.fixedWait(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.stopAfterDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();

// Error: Bad return type in lambda expression: DescribeResourceResult cannot be converted to ResourceNotFoundException
deleteResourceRetryer.call(() -> describeResource(resourceId));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not so familar with Guava's `Retryer`, thus after short investigation I was not able to find ready-to-use `StopStrategy`, so my advice is to implement it yourself

```
static class OnResourceNotFoundExceptionStopStrategy implements StopStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldStop(Attempt attempt) {
        if (attempt.hasException() 
                     && attempt.getExceptionCause() instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

With that strategy retries will stop when you'll catch `ResourceNotFoundException`. After that fix types and correctly define `Retryer`

```
final Retryer<DescribeResourceResult> deleteResourceRetryer = RetryerBuilder
            .<DescribeResourceResult>newBuilder()
            .retryIfResult(Predicates.notNull())
            .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.fixedWait(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .withStopStrategy(new OnResourceNotFoundExceptionStopStrategy())
            .build();
```

And finally, start retrying

```
try {
    deleteResourceRetryer.call(() -> describeResource(resourceId));
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // should not happens, because you will retry if any exception rather
    // than ResourceNotFoundException raised in your describeResource method
} catch (RetryException e) {
    // should not happens, because my implementation of StopStrategy
    // (as it looks in this example) is effectively infinite, until target exception.
    // For sure you're free to override it to anything you want
}
```

Hope it helps!